# Change logo url link

Tags: urls, links, logo

I'm trying to change the logo url of the site to "mywebsite.com/side2", but it is not working, can anyone tell me where is the error in the code below?

```
add_filter( 'login_headerurl', 'custom_loginlogo_url' );
function custom_loginlogo_url($url) {

return home_url( 'side2' );
}
```

Comment: Hi, are you trying to change the url of the homepage logo? or the login panel?

Comment: The homepage logo

Comment: @JackJohansson I found out what is wrong, the login_headerurl function is for the login page and what I want is for the main logo of the site, do you know what is the function for the url of the main logo of the site? You were right!

Comment: Yes i just posted an answer about that. Copy the part of your `header.php` that generates the URL to your question, and i will update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `login_headerurl` filter is for changing the logo url of login page, according to the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_headerurl).

To change the logo URL of your homepage, you will have to look into your theme's `header.php` file. You logo and it's link are included there. Depending on your theme, they way that your URL is generated may be different.

Access your `header.php` file from `Appearance > Edit` in the admin panel, and search for the line containing the logo. There, you can change it to whatever you want.

Comment: Ok, but I need to change the link in function.php, because the link will vary according to the user profile. The above script is only the part that changes the url.

Comment: You can change it based on user in `headers.php` too. If the theme developer is simply using a `bloginfo(url)` to output the URL, there is no way to change it using `functions.php`, unless you change the ENTIRE `bloginfo()` functions, or any other function used.

Answer (score 3):

If the theme author is using `bloginfo('url')` to output the url, then you can do the following.

`bloginfo('url')` is a wrapper for `echo get_bloginfo('url')` which is a wrapper for `home_url()` which in turn is a wrapper for `get_home_url()`. The code for that function is available [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L2989).

As can be seen, there is a filter available at the end of the function that you can use to change the value of the home url.

Edited so that the filters only fire for the home_url and custom_logo filters are both called.

```
add_filter( 'home_url', 'wpse_106269_home_url', 10, 4 );
function wpse_106269_home_url( $url, $path, $orig_scheme, $blog_id ) {
  add_filter( 'custom_logo', 'wpse_106269_custom_logo', 10, 2 );
}

function wpse_106269_custom_logo( $html, $blog_id ) {
  //* Remove the filter
  remove_filter( 'custom_logo', 'wpse_106269_custom_logo', 10, 2 );

  //* Use str_replace() to change link
  return str_replace( $old_url, $new_url, $html );
}
```

Comment: Good function in case he wants to change every single `bloginfo('url')` in his website so that the old URL becomes unreachable!

Comment: good point. changed answer so that it works only when custom_logo() and home_url() are called in conjunction

Answer (score 2):

You can Use this function to change the Logo url in Wordpress.

### Simple add this code in function.php file

```
//changing the url on the logo to redirect them
function mb_login_url() {  return home_url(); }
add_filter( 'login_headerurl', 'mb_login_url' );

// changing the alt text on the logo to show your site name
function mb_login_title() { return get_option( 'blogname' ); }
add_filter( 'login_headertitle', 'mb_login_title' );
```

---

### To change the Logo in Admin side login page

```
function my_login_logo_one() { 
?> 
<style type="text/css"> 
body.login div#login h1 a {
background-image: url(http://sitetitle.com/logo-1.png);  
}
</style>
<?php }
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_login_logo_one' );
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else if facing the same issue, I created the plugin [SMNTCS Custom Logo Link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/smntcs-custom-logo-link/) a while ago, which works with all themes that have 100.000+ active installations. If the theme that you're using is not among those themes, simply create an issue on https://github.com/nielslange/smntcs-custom-logo-link/issues and I'm happy to extend the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add this jQuery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){  
        $("a.logo-class").attr("href", "https://google.com");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking the following Javascript-based approach which worked for my purposes. I am using the theme from https://theme.co/x. I installed the Insert Headers and Footers plugin and then added the following Javascript (Footer section):

```
<script>
    document.getElementsByClassName('x-brand')[0].setAttribute("href", "https://example.com");
</script>
```

You will need to change the `'x-brand'` to point to the class of the logo href element specific for the given theme you are using.

Comment: I think it would be better to fix the page though. I'd be nervous the browser would start loading the old image, or there might be brief a layout jump if you don't have height and width attributes on them. There must be a way to change it in your theme.

Comment: Agreed. It's not the ideal solution but I spent about an hour looking for a way to change it in the theme, including looking through the theme's code, and couldn't find a way.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **get_page_by_path** as follows:

```
add_filter( 'login_headerurl', 'custom_loginlogo_url' );
function custom_loginlogo_url($url) {

  return get_page_by_path( 'side2' );
}
```

Comment: using the get_page_by_path as you suggested above did not work!