# change wordpress website logo url

Tags: theme-development, themes

I am trying to change my word-press logo website .But I am not able to solve this .

```
<?php
add_filter( 'login_headerurl', 'custom_loginlogo_url' );
function custom_loginlogo_url($url) {
    $link = 'http://www.example.com/';
    return $link;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow this link same question here**

[Change logo url link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/256717/change-logo-url-link/256718)

Comment: Vivek Tamrakar@@ you are very sure this is working code @ I used but not working so i just update , you have any other solution

Comment: @sanjay yes i'm sure it's working

Comment: Vivek Tamrakar@@can you suggest me a right script on this answer , clearly

Comment: @sanjay first answer are correct

Comment: ok let me know how can i put the my external link in this script . they are working for blog or other

Comment: Vivek Tamrakar@@ can you share me your answer with my question

Comment: Vivek Tamrakar@@ you there?

Comment: are try to change logo or url?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60750/discussion-between-sanjay-and-vivek-tamrakar).